# Chinese internationalization issue in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, struts2

I am working in struts2.0 application with internationalization Apart from Chinese it working fine in other languages.

When I put Chinese character in jsp I am not getting same values  in Action. Please help me for the same.

I have also used the UTF-8 pageEncoding

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I have a text box in the jsp in which I'm filling some Chinese character.

But in the Action class on the server side when I try to retrieve the value of the text box,I'm getting junk characters.

I'm not able to add the screen shot as I don't have 10 reputations.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you make GET/POST to send the data ? and you are recieving junk characters on client side/server ?

Comment: I'm using POST and getting the junk characters on server side (Action Class)

Comment: Did my proposed solution worked?

Answer (score 1):

In your action class before obtaining the parameters, set the request body encoding to the same encoding as the `pageEncoding` of the JSP.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps!

P.S Above mentioned solution applies to `POST` request only.

**EDIT**:

Get `HttpServletRequest` in calling method of your action class:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

and then set `request` property as mentioned above.

**EDIT2**:

Add this line to your `JSP`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
```

and add this `filter` in your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: any idea how to implement the samr in struts 2.0

Comment: no it did not work even after setting the request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); Still getting junk characters

Answer (score 0):

Try the following thing in your `jsp` page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently i faced an issue i.e. from jsp when I copy pasting a chinese character in name textbox and when i am trying to fetch that in Java DAO layer i get some junk value for name. With below code i have fixed the issue and i can get the chinese value same as in jsp.

```
String name = new String(entityObj.getName().getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```